# React Native App crashes when trying to debug remotely and does not work again unless re-installed

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

The Application was working fine until the installation of React-native-Reanimated library but has started to crash post installation when trying to debug remotely. It wouldn't even start again unless re-installed and shows this error:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstance.getSourceURL()' on a null object reference

[image: Error message]

The app was not starting but following the installation instructions in the React Reanimated docs got it to work but it now crashes every time I try to connect to a remote debugger.

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^6.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.3",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mentioned in their documentation that remote debugging is no longer possible for react-native-reanimated.

*As the library uses JSI for synchronous native methods access, remote debugging is no longer possible. You can use Flipper for debugging your JS code, however connecting debugger to JS context which runs on the UI thread is not currently supported.*

ref : [React Native Reanimated Known problems and limitations](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/#known-problems-and-limitations)

To use Flipper, refer this doc : [Debugging React Native apps with Flipper](https://blog.logrocket.com/debugging-react-native-apps-flipper/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems like Remote Debugging is not possible after installation of reanimated 2, using Flipper for debugging instead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had it too, just open the listbox on the right side of the Terminal-> select react native: run android. It worked for me.

[image: Screenshot]